# Why doesn't my iptables entries block pinging a Xen virtual machine?

Tags: linux, iptables, xen

I'm writing a bash script to add simple firewalling for Xen.

Here's the actual firewall configuration :

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp any
ACCEPT     esp  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     ah   --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ipp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW udp dpt:ha-cluster
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:https
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

I'd like to add a new chain for each of my virtual machines (each of them has a virtual interface called vif1.0, vif2.0, etc). Output interface (bridge) is xenbr0.

Here's what I do (for example to block ping 'in'to domU1, vif1.0) :

```
iptables -N domUFirewall
iptables -I FORWARD -j domUFirewall
iptables -I INPUT -j domUFirewall
iptables -A domUFirewall -i vif1.0 -p icmp -j DROP
```

But .. it doesn't work, i'm still able to ping in/out the domU.

Must be something really 'dumb' but I can't find out what's wrong.

Any clues ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using XEN with bridged networking, packets are being intercepted at a level before ordinary iptables commands can influence them.  Thus, you'll probably need to use the `ebtables` command to influence packet routing in the way that you want to.

- [ebtables/iptables interaction on a Linux-based bridge](http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html)
- [ebtables(8) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ebtables)
- [Xen Wiki * XenNetworking](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenNetworking)

Original answer left below that will work for other configurations, but not for XEN with bridged networking.

I am going to pretend for the sake of example that the IP address of `vif1.0` is 192.168.1.100.

I would redo the logic to not check the input device, but to instead check by IP Address. At the input chain, the packet is coming from (say) device `eth0`, not from `vif1.0`.  Thus, this rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i vif1.0 -j domUFirewall
```

that I previously proposed will never match any packets.  However, if you do the following, it should do what you want:

```
iptables -I INPUT -d 192.168.1.100 -j domUFirewall
```

where in this case the chain `domUFirewall` is set up by:

```
iptables -N domUFirewall
iptables -F domUFirewall
iptables -A domUFirewall -p icmp -j DROP
```

If a given chain is for a single device, then you want to make this check **before** jumping into the chain, on a rule with the "`-j chainName`" action.  Then, in the chain itself, you never have to check for the device or IP Address.

Second, I would always flush (empty) the chain in your script, just in case you're re-running the script.  Note that when you rerun the script, you may get complaints on the `-N` line.  That's OK.

There are other ways you could do this, but to give a different example, I would need to know specifically how your VM is set up -- bridged networking?  NAT?  Etc.  But the example I gave here should work in any of these modes.

Here are some useful links for the future:

- [Quick HOWTO, Ch14: Linux Firewalls Using iptables](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch14_:_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables)
- [Sandbox a VMware Virtual Machine With iptables](http://lonnieolson.com/blog/2007/08/27/sandbox-a-vmware-virtual-machine-with-iptables/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DMU        all  --  vif1.0 any     anywhere             anywhere
 2542 1208K RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Comment: Chain DMU (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere

Comment: interface vif1.0 is correct, but still able to ping. DMU jump rule in INPUT chain is the first entry, but still not filtering.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what the problem is ... thinking about it ...

Comment: I think the INPUT chain is maybe not the right place to check for this, but I'm not sure what is.  I'll have to fiddle with my myself.  If I can find a working answer I'll update this post.

Comment: Is there any 'simple' example ? INPUT is actually parsed but not chains i put there with 'jump'. Running redhat, maybe iptables is different ?

Comment: OK, after thinking about it overnight, I put in place a different answer that I hope will help.  I added a couple links that I think you'll find useful.

Comment: Ok checked out the links. Nothing useful there.

Oh, i forgot to mention it's a bridged configuration :

Comment: bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
xenbr0          8000.00e0813169fc       no              vif1.0
                                                        eth0
If that helps ...

Comment: one more news : iptables -A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in vif7.0 --physdev-out  vif7.0  -j ACCEPT
iptables: Unknown error 4294967295

Comment: Does this mean my answer above does not work?

Comment: How does my answer above fail?  The rules apply fine but you can still ping from another machine into the virtual machine?

Comment: Yes, so it's not working, the goal is to block 'ping' (or any other service) from the bridge to any other vif.

Comment: But from where are you trying to ping?  From the same machine or from another machine?

Comment: Is the chain domUFirewall actually getting called?  We need to figure out where the failure is.

Comment: Actually, not. Since iptables -L -v gives '0' packets being matched.
Trying to add a '-m physdev' parameter gives the '4294967295' error (see above)

Comment: Are you adding on the FORWARD or the INPUT chain?  (or both)

Comment: tried both; i see that FORWARD chain is not being called at all (0 packets)

Comment: OK, the xen bridge must be doing something I'm not aware of ... it must be intercepting these packets before they get to the normal packet filter, or otherwise handling them in some special way ... research is called for....

Comment: You may have to use ebtables....

Comment: Problem is that with xenserver you can't add any other repositories ...

Comment: Are you saying that the ebtables command is not present on your xen host server?

Comment: Yep, part of the 'citrix' politics ... but i think it's a simple centos base; i'll try to fetch them manually and keep you up.

Comment: ok, bad news; ebtables doesn't seem to exist on centos :(

Comment: Compiling from source ... in the meantime; what could be the config for ebtables to handle vif's etc ?

Comment: OK, while it's compiling, let's try a few last iptables commands ... try   iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -d xx.xx.xx.xx -p icmp -j DROP

Comment: I'm looking at http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html to try to figure out how the packets jump between iptables chains and ebtables chains, and how the ip address, ethernet address, etc, change at each step.

Comment: Yowza!!!  Check out this diagram of packet flow:  http://ebtables.sourceforge.net/br_fw_ia/PacketFlow.png

Comment: Yess !! 
Finally got it working ! 
After installing ebtables, i've been able to put the rules inside. Works like a charm now ! Thank you very very very much for your help !

Comment: Excellent!  Glad we got it working.